# Can Solana program Instruction's parameter be an Array or Vec?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, bubblegum

kinda bump into an issue and not sure what's the problem. I wonder whether the instruction's parameter can be a Vec or an Array?
for example:

```
# on-chain program
pub struct foo {
    a: u8,
    b: Pubkey,
    c: [u8; 32],
}

pub fn myfunction<'info>(
    ctx: Context<'info, MyCpiContext<'info>>,
    params: Vec<foo>,
) {...}

# client program
type foo {
   a: number,
   b: string,
   c: number[],
}
const param: foo[] = [...]
const ix = await this.client.program.methods
   .myfunction(param)
   .accounts({
      ...
   })
   .remainingAccounts(remainingAccounts)
   .instruction()
```

According to the example above, I not sure if I'm if there's syntax or logistic error. I keep getting `TypeError: src.reduce is not a function` error message while sending transaction to on-chain program.

Answer (score 2):

Send the vec through in your instruction data, not in the account struct :)

```
#[instruction(a: u8, b: [u8;32)]
pub struct foo {
    b: PubKey
}
```